# How to open a jquery dialog inside the iterate of a $.each?

Tags: jquery, json

I have to load some data from a json array object into an HTML form using jquery.  The issue is that as I iterate on the json objects the user has to validate the input for each row.  I have attempted to do this but I always end with just the last value loaded into the form as seen in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hQwwV/, but the user has to validate each pair in the dialog not just the last one. If there's a different way I should be trying this I'm open to try it as well as long as I can loop on the json items since I don't know the size or the contents of the array ahead of time.

sample Code:

```
var json = [
        {"id":"1","tagName":"apple"},
        {"id":"2","tagName":"orange"},
        {"id":"3","tagName":"banana"},
        {"id":"4","tagName":"watermelon"},
        {"id":"5","tagName":"pineapple"}
    ];

    $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    $("#id").val(obj.id);
    $("#tagName").val(obj.tagName);
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 400,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "I've read and understand this": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to show all of them on the same dialog? You only have one input, so as it loops through each of them, it's just overwriting the previous value with the next until it gets to the last one.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use just one input.  Is that possible? In the real application, once the user verifies the input it will submit it to the database and move on to the next set of data.

Comment: Then you need a way of looping through each the data pairs, like saving the current one to a variable, and adding a next button which replaces the values of the inputs until they get to the last one, then enables the complete button. It's either that, or appending input pairs for each one inside of the `$.each` loop.

Comment: As you can see I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to jquery.  What do I accomplish by saving it to a variable? How does that help the user validate the input and store that verified "Row" of data to database?  Will the variable somehow stop the dialog on the correct entry?

Comment: The idea/logic is to disable the "I've read and understand this" button, find a method to store the current iteration/index of the JSON object array they are verifying, and have them click next through each one. Each time they click next, it updates the input fields, and saves the index number to the variable. Once the index number reaches the total number of objects in the array, you can assume all are verified, and the "I've read and understand this" is enabled. That's the proper way to accomplish it while keeping a single input box for each field on the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your logic to not use an each, but wait on the user input to proceed to the next.  You can use promises or something more complex, but simply dequeuing a queue would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/hQwwV/1/

```
var json = [
    {"id":"1","tagName":"apple"},
    {"id":"2","tagName":"orange"},
    {"id":"3","tagName":"banana"},
    {"id":"4","tagName":"watermelon"},
    {"id":"5","tagName":"pineapple"}
];

var queue = json.slice(0);

processValidationQueue(queue);

function processValidationQueue(queue) {
    var itm = queue.pop();
    $("#id").val(itm.id);
    $("#tagName").val(itm.tagName);
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 400,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "I've read and understand this": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if (queue.length > 0) {
                    processValidationQueue(queue);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but it sounds like a step in the right direction.